# How to pass set_value of form_dropdown in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

i am creating a dynamic dropdown which has two fields only and fetching data from db.
While editing that i can show user selected value for first field but in second field which depend on the first field doesnt show user selected value but it shows the field when changing the first, that too based on changing value using onchange jquery function.

Now my question is how to pass the set_value of dropdown to jquery val() funtion.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#drop-down-id").find(":selected").val();
```

Then you can send this selected value to the post page.